# How to apply changes to multiple ui controls fitting a certain name pattern?

Tags: qt

```
ui->Pipe_1->setStyleSheet(ui->Pipe_1->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
" QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
ui->Pipe_2->setStyleSheet(ui->Pipe_2->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
" QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
ui->Pipe_3->setStyleSheet(ui->Pipe_3->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
" QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
ui->Pipe_4->setStyleSheet(ui->Pipe_4->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
" QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
ui->Pipe_5->setStyleSheet(ui->Pipe_5->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
" QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
ui->Pipe_6->setStyleSheet(ui->Pipe_6->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
" QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
ui->Pipe_7->setStyleSheet(ui->Pipe_7->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
" QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
```

I have this kind of code and I wanted to take in a for loop to reduce my codes. The pipes are instances of `QProgressBar`.

I tried that:

```
for(x=1; x<75; x++){
QString y="Pipe_&d,x";
ui->Pipe_1->setObjectName(y);
ui->Pipe_1->setStyleSheet(ui->Pipe_1->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
        " QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
}
```

But it didnt work how can I handle? Thank you for your answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very easily find all children matching a certain name pattern:

```
// C++11
auto pipes = findChildren<QProgressBar*>(QRegExp("Pipe_[0-9]+"));
for (pipe : pipes) {
  pipe->setStyleSheet(pipe->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
    " QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
}

// C++98
QList<QProgressBar*> pipes = findChildren<QProgressBar*>(QRegExp("Pipe_[0-9]+"));
foreach (pipe, pipes) {
  pipe->setStyleSheet(pipe->property("defaultStyleSheet").toString() +
    " QProgressBar::chunk { background: #D7DF01; }");
}
```

Comment: What's the performance of this like?  I tend to avoid `findChildren(..)` as it looks slow, but admittedly I've never looked at the implementation.

Comment: @cmannett85 It simply iterates the child list and applies the regex to the object name. Nothing particularly bad about it. It performs about as well as member lookup using a runtime string argument would work in javascript. So nothing to scoff at.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 75 progress bars in your UI?  Anyway, this is a prime example of why more seasoned Qt UI developers don't use Qt Designer.  If you were hand coding your UI, you would just store the pointers in an array as you built them and iterated through later.

As for your current problem you could set the `objectName` property in Qt Designer and then use `QObject::findChild(..)` to retrieve them dynamically, or use Boost::PreProcessor to build the statements for you, or derive from `QProgressBar` and set the stylesheet in the constructor.

Comment: Qt Designer already sets proper object names. They are the same as variable names. There is, in fact, no way to set them to be anything else. So it is in fact very easy to iterate over any textual variable pattern.

Comment: @KubaOber You're right, it's been awhile since I've used it.